# How to suppress "Not collecting exported resources without storeconfigs"?

Tags: puppet

I'm getting the following in my Puppet master syslog over and over:

```
Sep 27 11:52:05 puppet1 puppet-master:  Not collecting exported resources without storeconfigs
Sep 27 11:52:06 puppet1 puppet-master:  Not collecting exported resources without storeconfigs
Sep 27 11:52:06 puppet1 puppet-master:  Not collecting exported resources without storeconfigs
```

I'm not actually using storeconfigs:

```
[ashinn@puppet1 ~]$ cat /etc/puppet/puppet.conf
[agent]
server                    = puppet.mydomain.com
environment               = production
report                    = true

[main]
logdir                    = /var/log/puppet
vardir                    = /var/lib/puppet
ssldir                    = /var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir                    = /var/run/puppet
factpath                  = $vardir/lib/facter
pluginsync                = true
certname                  = puppet1.mydomain.com

[master]
modulepath                = $confdir/environments/$environment/modules
manifest                  = $confdir/environments/$environment/manifests/site.pp
templatedir               = $confdir/templates
autosign                  = $confdir/autosign.conf
ssl_client_header         = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
ssl_client_verify_header  = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY
report                    = true
reports                   = hipchat
```

Any way I can suppress these messages? What do they actually come from?

Comment: Do you have any exported resources or collectors defined in manifests?  (http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_exported.html)

Comment: I just grepped through my Puppet repository for `@@` and there are a handful of exported resources scattered through modules that I use on most nodes.

Answer (score 1):

What is output of following command?

```
$ puppet config print | grep storeconfigs
```

And then check puppet master:

```
$ puppet master --configprint all | grep store
```

I assume you can set in `puppet.conf`:

```
storeconfigs = false
```

Or you can setup e.g. puppetDB as a backend storage for your configs and the message should disappear. Have a look at [introducing puppetDB](http://puppetlabs.com/blog/introducing-puppetdb-put-your-data-to-work)

Comment: [ashinn@workerstage2 ~]$ puppet config print | grep storeconfigs
async_storeconfigs = false
storeconfigs = false
storeconfigs_backend = active_record
thin_storeconfigs = false

Comment: ok, check the master's setting

Comment: Both same: `[ashinn@puppet1 ~]$ puppet config print | grep storeconfigs
async_storeconfigs = false
storeconfigs = false
storeconfigs_backend = active_record
thin_storeconfigs = false`

Comment: mmnt, have you tried the `puppet master --configprint all | grep store`?